# Is there a way to get the ID or name of the current presentation?

Tags: google-slides-api

Try to create a document in the same folder of the presentation but I seem to need to have the ID or name to get the ID of the parent folder and I cant seem to find any thing that does that.

Nothing that I tried worked I.e.

```
function getparentfolderid(){
Var ss = slidesapp.getactivepresentation();
Var tt = slidesapp(ss.getid())
Var file = driveapp.getfilebyid(ss);
var folder = file.getparents();
var parentfoldername = folder.next().getname();
logger.log(parentfoldername);
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I need the ID of the folder that my current presentation is in.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `I need the ID of the folder that my current presentation is in.` of your reply, if you want to retrieve the parent folder ID of the active presentation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Slide and save the script.

```js
function sample() {
  const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const fileId = s.getId();
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  const parent = file.getParents().next();
  const parentFolderId = parent.getId();
  console.log(parentFolderId); // Show parent folder ID in the log.

  const parentFolderName = parent.getName();
  console.log(parentFolderName); // Show parent folder name in the log.
}
```

- When this script is run, the parent folder ID and the parent folder name can be seen in the log.

#### References:

- [getFileById(id) of Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
- [getParents() of Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)

Comment: @Stanley Levine About `That works great - thank you`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer